# How to check runtime that is there any changes in image(16bit,gray-scale) in myApp using java?

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm making desktop app in Java Swing.

In my app I do some image processing on my image which is a 16 bit, Gray-Scale and tiff image.

In my app the user can open images from tree using drag and drop of image into a `JDesktopPane`.

Now when user done some process on image like Remove Noise or set Contrast, when they close the image my app should ask if they want to Save Changes in Image?

So how can i check run time that some changes in Original image?

Comment: I wouldn't.  Any time you apply a filter/change to the image, I'd simply raise a flag indicating that a change has occurred

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for replay. i know that, i can use flag that true when some imageProcess function event fire. But , i don't want to use flag.Can i check or detect any changes in image , by using BufferedImage Or Other class in java?

Comment: Write the images out to separate files and do a MD5 compare on the files

Answer (score 1):

The `java.awt.image.Raster` contained in a `BufferedImage` does *not* override `Object#equals()`. This is largely because iterating over *w* * *h* pixels can get expensive: *O(wh)*. Any optimization depends on the nature of the change. If you're only looking for global changes, such as noise or contrast, comparing a number of samples may suffice.  You'll also want to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) your intended usage.